# Knockout validate child when parents are mutually exclusive

Tags: knockout.js

This is the scenario that I have:

I have items. Each item has a list of radio options on it. Options are the same across items.
When a radio option is selected, I need to check it is valid. 
I do this by checking that a mutually exclusive item does not have the same option selected.

Eg.

Item A
- Fund 1 
- Fund 2
- No Fund

Item B
- Fund 1
- Fund 2
- No Fund

Item C
- Fund 1
- Fund 2
- No Fund

Lets assume Item A and Item B are mutually exclusive.
So Fund 1 may be selected on Item A, but not on Item B. If this happens, Item A and Item B are invalid. But, Fund 1 may be selected on A and C or B and C.

How would I go about doing this using knockout?
What is the best way to structure it?

I have a list of Items, each has a list of radio options with a 'selected' property.
I'm subscribing to the selected property and the idea is to update a flag on the parent property (Item) to indicate if the item can be selected. This will need to be done on all the parent properties when any of the child properties change. It doesn't seem like a good idea to update the parent from a child. Any ideas/suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the basic issue is that `Item A` and `Item B` can't have the same value, `Item C` is somewhat irrelevant from what I understand as it will always be valid.

You can use a `computed` to determine equality when selections are made on the two radio button lists. As you haven't provided sample code, I've created a demo to illustrate:

### [JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dq6atjws/1)

**HTML:**

```
<p>Item A: 
   <span class="error" data-bind="visible: !isValidA()">Invalid Selection</span>
</p>
<div data-bind="foreach: optionValues">
    <input type="radio" name="optionsGroup1" 
           data-bind="attr: {value: value}, 
                      checked: $root.selectionA" /> 
    <span data-bind="text: label"></span>
</div>

<p>Item B: 
   <span class="error" data-bind="visible: !isValidB()">Invalid Selection</span>
</p>
<div data-bind="foreach: optionValues">
    <input type="radio" name="optionsGroup2" 
           data-bind="attr: {value: value}, 
                      checked: $root.selectionB" /> 
    <span data-bind="text: label"></span>
</div>

<p>Item C: 
   <span class="error" data-bind="visible: !isValidC()">Invalid Selection</span>
</p>
<div data-bind="foreach: optionValues">
    <input type="radio" name="optionsGroup3" 
           data-bind="attr: {value: value}, 
                      checked: $root.selectionC" /> 
    <span data-bind="text: label"></span>
</div>
```

**ViewModel:**

```
var viewModel = {
    optionValues: [{
        "value": "1",
            "label": "Fund 1"
    }, {
        "value": "2",
            "label": "Fund 2"
    }, {
        "value": "0",
            "label": "No Fund"
    }],
    selectionA: ko.observable("0"),
    selectionB: ko.observable("0"),
    selectionB: ko.observable("0"),
    isValidA: ko.computed = function () {
        return (this.selectionA() !== this.selectionB())
            || (this.selectionA() === "0");
    },
    isValidB: ko.computed = function () {
        return (this.selectionA() !== this.selectionB()) 
            || (this.selectionB() === "0");
    },
    isValidC: ko.computed = function () {
        return true;
    }
};
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

The computed will recalculate each time the radio buttons change, so it can evaluate if the selection is valid and you can perform other logic based on it's result, in this case I'm simply controlling the visibility or the error label with the result.

All items are initialised to `No Fund` and it currently doesn't cause an error if `Item A` and `Item B` have the same selection of `No Fund`. To get this to cause an error simply remove the second part of the comparison in the computed to look something like this:

```
isValidA: ko.computed = function () {
    return this.selectionA() !== this.selectionB();
}
```

Comment: thanks! what if determining if the funds are mutually exclusive is based on a property on the fund. And that property must be updated when it is selected e.g. Select Fund1 - update the isMutuallyExclusive property to true on Fund1 for all items (A,B,C). Deselect Fund1 - update the isMutuallyExclusive property to false on Fund1 for all items. Similarly for the other funds

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. This logic will highlight the invalid state and you can add functionality into/or based on the computed value to perform other conditional logic. For example, `this.isMutallyExclusive(isValidA() && isValidB())`